# How to print out values of variables contained in an array partially unused in cplex

Tags: cplex

I want to print out the decision variables in cplex after cplex.solve(). However, the variables are contained in an array y[i][j][k] in which not all i,j,k's are used (i.e., some element in the array is not used in the model). As a result, cplex returns an error saying "object unknown to cplex" when trying to print out an unused element and hence terminates the printing. How can I print out all the used elements without triggering such an error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know which ones are being used?

You could do something like this:

```
public List<IloNumVar> getDecisionVars(){
    List<IloNumVar> vars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < iLim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < jLim; j++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < kLim; k++) {
                if (isUsed(y[i][j][k]) && model.getValue(y[i][j][k]) == 1) {
                    vars.add(y[i][j][k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return vars;
}    

private boolean isUsed(IloNumVar var){
    //logic to apply if it is used
}
```

Hope this helps